# Company shelling 100% stake to another company

Tags: company-policy

I joined my current employer 5 months back. Now my company has sold its 100% stake to other company. How will it  impact my employment , Will I get a confirmation letter, which is due 2nd week of  next month.

Will the other company will take me on their payroll or I will be asked to leave the company.

Please advise as it is just 5 month n where I go they asked the reason of change

Comment: Which country is this?

Comment: In general, senior managers are most at risk in a buyout. Whether you job is at risk depends on whether they bought the company because they wanted your product (usually you stay) or not. If they wanted business line A and not business line B, then you will likely be laid off if you work on B. If they just want the customers and are going to convert them to their product (when bought by a company that was a direct competitor), then you are likely to be kep until all clients are converted to the other product. with the expanded business, some people may be retained but most would go.

Answer (score 1):

> how does it will impact my employment , do i get the confirmation letter . which is due 2nd week of next month . Does the other company will take me on their payroll or I will be asked to leave the company..

No-one will know aside from the new company. However, it's always good to be over-cautious in these situations, as being laid off can be a real possibility. Update your CV and start keeping an eye out for relevant positions just in case.

Answer (score 1):

Addressing only the contractual parts of your question. Just because a company has been sold to another company that does not alter the contract of employment between you. Unless they​ tell you otherwise you are still employed under the same conditions as you were before. Even if your company is technically disbanded the owning company is obliged to adhere to the terms of your contract in most jurisdictions.

Whether they choose to make changes we cannot foresee, but no changes are triggered just because of the sale.

Answer (score 0):

Typically "buying the company" means taking over all liabilities, contracts and assets of the company being purchased. Your employment would fall into the "contracts" part of that, so the new company would have to honor it.

**That said, any changes to your employment situation not detailed in the contract should be clearly communicated to all employees before the deal is finalized.** (Office move, changes to benefit plans and soforth)

While this kind of thing can unnerve employees (layoffs certainly are possible if there are redundant employees after the merge) remember that the purchasing company almost certainly wants to keep the acquired company fully functional.

I should note that I was at a small company that was bought by a large company that sold it again just a few years later! I was employed all the while under the same terms, and other than office moves and nuanced policy changes, I kept my job until I decided to move on.